# Can I travel on other forms of U.S. identification traveling from US to BVI and back?

Tags: visas, air-travel, passports, paperwork, us-citizens

US passport is with French Consulate to obtain a student visa. I am traveling to the BVI's the day after I submit my application. Can I use my Massachusetts driver's license and U.S. birth certificate to travel, or my Canadian passport?

Comment: inconceivable. **You need a passport**

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you plan to fly there. While the authorities of the British Virgin Islands [will accept a birth certificate and driver's license for entry](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=US&DE=EIS&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=PEARL&subuser=PEARL), the US government requires that you have a [Western Hemisphere Travel Initiative](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/us-citizens/western-hemisphere-travel-initiative)-compliant document to travel in or out of the US by air. Unless you happen to have a Trusted Traveler Program card "(NEXUS, SENTRI or FAST)" or fall into an unusual exception (US military traveling on official orders, U.S. Merchant Mariner traveling on official business), that document will be a US passport.

If you can plan ahead, you can [obtain a second US passport](http://traveltips.usatoday.com/obtain-second-passport-legally-61904.html) so you can travel while your first passport is with the French consulate (or pay a passport service to get one for you), but the process is somewhat costly and cumbersome.

Comment: A US passport card, at $30, would be a less expensive alternative if the traveler plans to travel by sea (for example by flying to the US Virgin Islands and traveling to and from the British Virgin Islands by sea).

Comment: @phoog I couldn't find a definitive source that says you can enter the British Virgin Islands by sea with a US Passport card (if you can with a driver's license and birth certificate, you logically should be able to with a passport card of course), but yeah, there's more options if you're going by sea.

Comment: At least the birth certificate and the DL will get the traveler into the BVI and the passport card will get him back to the USVI, if the BVI don't accept the passport card (I agree that it would be somewhat illogical for them not to).

Comment: She does have a canadian passport, can she use that to get back into the states with her other US forms of ID? Yes she is traveling by air

Answer (score 0):

I recently traveled by car from Canada to the US and asked US customs officer my question. The answer is yes you can travel from the US to the BVI by air on a Canadian passport, that states you were born in the US.

Comment: Your question did not in its original form indicate that you are a dual citizen.